# Compilation Error when I try to resize box

Tags: tables, debugging

Firstly, I know that here was some similar problems, but I really can't get any problem solved.
Well, here is my problem: I have table that is so wide and gets outside slide. I tried to use `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}` in the first line above table and I got message:

```
missing \endcsname...
```

What should I do?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. Since you mention sldes, I assume your MWE would be in the form of a single `beamer` frame with a resized table in it.

Comment: It is impossible to debug that without more information, but also are you sure you want to resize a table (which is very much only something to do as a last resort, it produces inconsistent font sizes, and there are usually far less destructive ways to fit a table to a page)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given many clues but I would guess you *just* added `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}` without putting the entire table in the third `{.....}` argument.

If you really must scale the table (and really, it's almost never a good plan)

```
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    a&b\\
  \end{tabular}%
}
```

with the entire `tabular` in the argument to `\resizebox`.

If you do

```
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    a&b\\
  \end{tabular}
```

then that is the same as

```
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin}
  {tabular}{cc}
    a&b\\
  \end{tabular}
```

so the argument of `\resizebox` is just `\begin` so at some point it will execute `\begin` divorced from the environment name `tabular` which is quite likely to generate multiple errors including missing csname.